# Java compilation problem -- default methods not allowed

Tags: java, maven

I am developing a Java program and just wanting to compile when I ran into this odd error (included below).   I am using java version "1.8.0_31" and I do not
have any other version installed on my MAC.
Can anyone tell me what this error is?  I tried google'ing but didn't reveal anything relevant yet.   Thanks

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project inspectorBee: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /Users/vincentyau1/Development/testingbee/inspectorbee/src/main/java/io/beeCloud/inspectorBee/resources/execution/Executable.java:[9,9] default methods are not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR] (use -source 8 or higher to enable default methods)
[ERROR] /Users/vincentyau1/Development/testingbee/inspectorbee/src/main/java/io/beeCloud/inspectorBee/service/InspectorBeeService.java:[125,68] diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR] (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
```

Comment: The source parameter for the compilation is set to 1.5. Adjust the parameter value in the properties

Comment: @KevinO  how do I adjust that?  I do not see such a field in pom.xml.

Comment: It is in the project.xml.

Comment: @KevinO  I do not see project.xml anywhere in my project source tree.  I also searched my entire hard drive and don't see it either.  Where do I find this file?

Comment: unless you are referring to pom.xml.  And I cannot see such a field in pom.xml either.

Comment: Usually set in the project, but can be set in the pom.xml also: https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-tell-maven-to-use-java-8/

Comment: But I believe this approach is the preferred: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

Comment: thanks.  Problem solved.  I added:  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>